# Find Host of Hyper-V VM via PowerShell

Tags: hyper-v, powershell-5.0

I want to use PowerShell to generate a list of Hyper-V hosts and their hosted VMs. After which, I want to do a search for the VM is hosted on which Hyper-V.

I already have the first portion which is to generate a list of Hyper-V hosts and their list their hosted VMs and exported to a text file. The output appears something like this:

```
----HyperV Hostname ----
state   VM Name
Running VmHostname A
Running VMHostname B
Off     VMHostname C
```

Below is my original code.

```bsh
Write-Host "Get list of VM on listed Hyper-Vs"
$enddate = (Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
$filename = $enddate + "-vmlist.txt"

$hostlist = 1..137 | ForEach-Object {"MyHostname$_"}
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

foreach ($host_vm in $host_list) {
    echo "---$host_vm---" 
    Write-Host "Populating $host_vm..."
    Get-VM -ComputerName $host_vm | ft State, Name -AutoSize
}
Write-Host "Completed"
```

Comment: Don't write your data to a flat text file first. Create a hashtable mapping the Hyper-V host names to the list of their VMs. Use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`.

Comment: Hi. Currently reading up on hashtables. I can't imagine how this fits in as each VM is kinda like nested out in a table format.

Comment: Using a hashtable gives you a data structure like this (using JSON notation): `{"host_A": [{"Name": "vm_X", "State": "Running"}, {"Name": "vm_Y", "State": "Off"}, ...], ...}`. You can then traverse this structure in order to extract the information you're looking for. For instance, `$hashtable['host_A']` will give you a list of all VMs from that that host.

Comment: okay...after reading more on hashtables i know what this means. But i will need to loop it first because all my host are in sequence from 1-137. then each of this host need to do a get-VM...and then to fit all these in a hashtable....I also want to do be able to do a search after generating out the list and I have no idea how.

Comment: The first loop could be integrated with the second loop, but since the first loop should be pretty fast it doesn't really matter. And yes, you need to populate the hashtable first before you can work with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "after generating out the list"?

Comment: Ohh I meant as in after going through the loops and hashtables and what not, I wanna be able to search which vm is hosted at which host.

Comment: With a hashtable in the abovementioned format you could do that like this: `$ht.Keys | Where-Object { $ht[$_].Name -contains 'vm_Y' }`.